# Handle onError image on mapping React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this images iterating, and only on error of image I have to add a background color to the parent element div. So my code is like this

```js
 
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import COLORS from 'core/colors/colors'
...

export const ComponentSample: React.FC = () => {
 
 const [imagePlaceholder, setImagePlaceholder] = useState(false)
  const addDefaultSrc = (ev) => {
   
    if (!ev.currentTarget.onerror) {
      setImagePlaceholder(true)
    }
    ev.target.src = 'https://socialistmodernism.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/placeholder-image.png?w=640'
    ev.currentTarget.className = styles.placeholderImg;
  }
  console.log(imagePlaceholder)
  const colors = Object.values(COLORS)
  const randomColor = imagePlaceholder ? colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)] : COLORS.white

 return <div className={styles.container}>
 <div className={styles.imageContainer} key={index} style={{ backgroundColor: randomColor }} >
                      <img src={project.thumbnailUrl} onError={addDefaultSrc} className={styles.imagePost} />
 
 </div>
 
 }
```

The problem here is  that imagePlaceholder is becoming true and always returning true, I don't know how to make only on image that has error

Comment: `if (!ev.currentTarget.onerror) {` inside the error handler doesn't make sense. The error has already fired. Plus, the test itself doesn't make sense, because every image has a handler.

Comment: @lilo why not use a ternary expression to set the image to a default value if it has error or set it to the other value if there is none. Just for simplicity

Comment: @lilo what does project.thumbnailUrl show? if this is invalid or throws error, then it will run the function, if the url is valid and image loads, it will return false.